# Unexpected end of JSON input error in AWS Lambda SQS function

Tags: node.js, json, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

This is my nodejs app serverless lambda function

```
export const updateDailyForecastResults: SQSHandler = async (event) => {
  console.log('Function invoked!!!!');
  await env.check();
  event.Records.forEach(record => {
    const { body } = record;
    console.log(body);
  });
  return;
};
```

And I am sending was document example sqs event

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "messageId": "059f36b4-87a3-44ab-83d2-661975830a7d",
      "receiptHandle": "AQEBwJnKyrHigUMZj6rYigCgxlaS3SLy0a...",
      "body": "test",
      "attributes": {
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "SentTimestamp": "1545082649183",
        "SenderId": "AIDAIENQZJOLO23YVJ4VO",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1545082649185"
      },
      "messageAttributes": {},
      "md5OfBody": "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6",
      "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:my-queue",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or I tried other versions of Json objects but always I got the same error which is

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:98:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
  ]
}
```

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this lambda invoked through API gateway? if yes, you should follow the response format: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html

Answer (score 0):

this exception means that your code has a syntax error.

It occurs before processing the event, so it does not really matter what event you'll give it.

Can you share all the code (and the dependencies)?